# Should I call my license file LICENSE, LICENSE.md, or LICENSE.txt?

Tags: license-file

Are there any stylistic conventions governing the choice of file extension to use for the license file in an open source project? I see `LICENSE`, `LICENSE.md`, and `LICENSE.txt` all being commonly used, and I know there's no functional difference between them (at least in terms of applying the license itself), but is there any reason to prefer one over the others?

Comment: GitHub seems to prefer just `LICENSE` with their "Choose a license template". In absence of anything else, that might be enough to base my decision on. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: LICENSE and LICENSE.txt are equivalent in basically every way. LICENSE.md will be treated and displayed as Markdown by some systems, including GitHub. There are no other differences; choosing between them is entirely down to personal preference.

Comment: There is nothing difference from a legal view.